# Firefox Ubuntu 16.10 not loading any google domains

Tags: firefox, 16.10, google

I have recently started having trouble where none of the google domain sites will load. At gmail.com the loading bar hangs half way. If I do get it to load, it is always waiting for plus.google or hangouts.google. I have refreshed Firefox to defaults. I have no extensions installed at all. I removed Firefox using the software store and reinstalled. Firefox is my browse of choice and was working for for months. With in the last two weeks I have to use chrome for google related sites and searches ( a real drag ). I have searched far and wide, but most information I find is a few years old and almost none of it s Linux.

i5-2520M 4GB Ram Ubuntu 16.10 64-bit Kernel 4.8.5 Gnome desktop environment Firefox 49.0.2

Comment: Could you try sudo apt-get install --reinstall firefox (if you're not afraid to lose personal configs and such) ?

Comment: I tried that as well as pulling the tar from Mozilla and running it from the extracted folder.